# multithreaded file download in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement multithreading using ExecutorService for downloading files parallely. Below is my code

```
   public void downloadFiles(List<String> filenames, final String fileSavePath) {
    if (filenames != null && filenames.size() > 0) {
        List<Callable<Void>> jobs = new ArrayList();
        for (final String fileName : filenames) {
            jobs.add(new Callable() {
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    downloadFile(fileName, fileSavePath);
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
        performJobs(jobs);
    }
}
```

My requirement is that i want to return a status from this method after all the files are downloaded succesfully. I am not sure how to do this. I cannot access variable of inner class from an outer one.

Any advice would be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Javadoc of Callable:

> A task that returns a result and may throw an exception. Implementors
>   define a single method with no arguments called call.

Taking a cue from this, change `List<Callable<Void>> jobs` to `List<Callable<Boolean>> jobs` and similarly change your return type of your `call` method. Using this, after completion of the task, you can then check the returned status.

Comment: Hi Sujay,
Thanks i implemented it as suggested and it works fine.
            'private boolean performJobs(List<Callable<Boolean>> jobs) {
  try {
   boolean jobDone = false;
   List<Future<Boolean>> futures = service.invokeAll(jobs);
   for (Future<Boolean> future : futures){
    jobDone = future.get();
    if(!jobDone)
     return jobDone;
   }
   return jobDone;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new IllegalStateException(e);
  } finally {
   service.shutdown();
  }
 }'

This works for me

Answer (score 4):

A `Callable` can return a result. When you submit a job to the executor service, you get a future back.  Calling `get()` on it will give you back the result returned by the `Callable` which can very well be the status of that particular download.

In your particular example, instead of returning `null`, return the result of downloading the file. Another way can be to use a shared thread-safe queue between the callables and add the status to that queue (though it's a roundabout way of doing stuff). You can also use this sort of trick to "update" some status on the UI etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).